# How to add where condition on sub query using sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to write a subquery where condition if that doesnt exist then the complete object should not display using sequelize. Here is my query

```
let dates = await UserEvent.findAll({
            where: {
                posted_by: {
                    [Op.not]: user_id
                },
                start_date_time: {
                    [Op.gte] : Date.now()
                },
                // '$event_interested.user_account_id$' : { [Op.not]: user_id},
            },
            subQuery: false,
            include: [
                {
                    model: User_Account,
                    as: 'user',
                    where: {
                        gender: gender
                    }
                },
                {
                    model: Event_Interest,
                    as: 'event_interested',
                    required: false,
                    duplicating: false,
                    where: {
                        user_account_id: {
                            [Op.not] : user_id
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
        })
```

Now if user_id exist on Event_Interest then I don't want to display that User_Event. But that I am not able to achieve. In the current scenario what is happening that if user_id exist on Event_Interest then only that interest is not displaying But User_Event is still displaying.

Any suggestion of great help.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set `required: true` for the `Event_Interest` model. If it is false, the Sequelize doing `OUTER JOIN`. So if you change it to the `true`, the query will be executed as `INNER JOIN` and if the UserEvent doesn't have Event_Interest you should not receive it in the output.

Example:

```
let dates = await UserEvent.findAll({
        where: {
            posted_by: {
                [Op.not]: user_id
            },
            start_date_time: {
                [Op.gte] : Date.now()
            },
            // '$event_interested.user_account_id$' : { [Op.not]: user_id},
        },
        subQuery: false,
        include: [
            {
                model: User_Account,
                as: 'user',
                where: {
                    gender: gender
                }
            },
            {
                model: Event_Interest,
                as: 'event_interested',
                required: true,
                duplicating: false,
                where: {
                    user_account_id: {
                        [Op.not] : user_id
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
    })
```